# How to create an applet in Java, in the latest version of Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, applet

The Applet class has been deprecated, and but online tutorials for creating java applets extends the Applet class. Is there a different way to create an applet without using the deprecated class?

Comment: Why do you want to create an Applet?  They are very much outdated.

Comment: Java 11 drops support for applets completely and most browsers won't run them, this is a dead technology.

Answer (score 2):

A distinct non-answer: you do **not** do that.

Not only the Applet class has been deprecated. That whole "technology/idea" is dead. No current browser does support running Java code any more. In other words: Java in the browser is dead. Learning about it is a waste of time and energy.

If you want to build a Java GUI, learn about Swing or JavaFX. If you want to create a web application that runs in a browser, there are many other ways to do that. Java applets is not a reasonable way in 2018.

Comment: Applets at the end of 2018 ... These are terrible...